# IOS Team Provisioning Profile in Xcode without Bundle Identifier

Tags: ios, xcode

I have developed and launched one app already, but now for second app, After creating IOS Team Provisioning Profile in Xcode my Bundle Identifier is missing only I can see *Asterisk

Comment: get the bundle identifier from the app id

Comment: Do you have Apple Developer Program subscription? you'd better to create explicit provisioning profiles for each app (not just Wildcard)

Comment: I got the bundle for app id as well, and yes i have the subscription. I am also trying to use explicit.

Comment: few days back I have created one app successfully

Comment: When I click Fix Issue in Xcode , it created a profile like this " IOS Team Provisioning Profile:*  "